# Conditional query between tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fill a table with the results of a query, however, the results of said query depends on the result of other queries and then it ends up having several thousand selects making the process really long. I was wondering if what i'm trying to achieve is possible through a single query.

What i want to do is this.

```
Table: Store
fields: storeid, store_name

Table: Product   
fields: codproduct, product_name, price1, price2

Table: PriceList 
fields: pricelistid, codproduct, storeid, price1, price2
```

I'm keeping base prices in the product record itself and custom prices per store in a the table called "PriceList". i get the storeid from the user that is logged in.

I'm currently running a query to let me know if there is a custom price from where the user is logged on, if there is none, then i use the base prices in the "productos" table. But i'm running several thousands of selects each time.

Is there a way to acchieve that in a single query?

the final query needs to return:
codproduct, product_name, price1, price2

price1 and price2 being the base price from "product" if there is no custom price in the "PriceList" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted correctly your question, here is a query that produces the result given the storeid X:

```
SELECT codproduct, 
       product_name, 
       COALESCE(l.price1, p.price1) AS price1, 
       COALESCE(l.price2, p.price2) AS price2
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN PriceList l ON p.codproduct = l.codproduct
WHERE storeid = X
```

Comment: That is super close except that there is a problem. If there are no records of said store for X product in PriceList then it doesn't return anything at all instead of returning p.price. Besides that it works how i want it so i'm just going to work around that. Thank you.

Comment: If there is no PriceList for a certain product then the left join should give null for all the fields of PriceList, so thereis always the price of the product.